# Access shipping/billing using hook in Store

Tags: expresso-store

I'm trying to make an extension that allows the user to choose from a list of shipping and billing addresses that they have previously entered. I'm using the store_order_complete_end hook listed here https://www.exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html but I can't access the addresses in the $order object because the $order->attributes object is a protected attribute. Is there any other way to get the addresses for the order?

```
public function my_store_order_complete_end($order) {
    $vars = $order->attributes; // undefined as it's protected
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the customer attributes are actually accessible as direct members of the `$order` object:

```
$order->billing_first_name
$order->billing_last_name
$order->billing_address1
$order->billing_city
```

Etc.

Comment: Thanks Derek. I didn't see those in the var_dump oddly enough but it works.